# Drawing Smooth lines with Quartz 2D

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I am creating a demo IOS application that will be a simple drawing app. I have used Quartz 2D to create a basic app. However, the lines that is draws are very jagged. Im looking for a way to apply anti-aliasing or blending to make the lines smooth. The drawLineFrom looks like this:

```
func drawLineFrom(fromPoint: CGPoint, toPoint: CGPoint) {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    tempImageView.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height))


    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, fromPoint.x, fromPoint.y)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, toPoint.x, toPoint.y)
    CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, true)
    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, true)


    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, brushWidth)
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, red, green, blue, 1.0)
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal)


    CGContextStrokePath(context)


    tempImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    tempImageView.alpha = opacity
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

}
```

The project can be found here: https://github.com/BananaSplitio/OpenSketch

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know I'm massively late to the party here but if you changed:

`UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)`

to

`UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, NO, 0.0f)`;

that should solve the jagged line issue. The last argument `0.0f` specifies the screen scale. Setting this to `0.0f` will automatically set it to the resolution of the device. Without this it draws it with 1 point = 1 pixel (so non retina), causing things to look jagged.